The asymptotic at infinity of ODE
It may be a simple problem in ODE.
Let $u$ be the positiv solution to
$$u''(t)-f(u,t)u(t)=0, u(0)=1, \lim_{t\to+\infty}=0,$$
with $f>0$ and $\lim_{t\to+\infty}f(u(t),t)=1$.
Can we prove that there eixsts a constant $C$ such that $\lim_{t\to+\infty} e^{t}u(t)=C$? I'd be grateful for any references.

Counterexample: $u(t)=(t/3+1)e^{-t}$ and $f(u,t)=\dfrac{t+1}{t+3}$.

Thanks for the counterexample in your reply, I updated my question now.
